# Facebook ios sdk (obj-c to swift) issue

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to bring obj-c code to swift (facebook ios sdk), but autocomplete(intellisense) does not work in handler and I get an error (marked in code) : Set NSObject does not have a member named 'containsObject'

```
@IBAction func loginWithFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {
        /*
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
        // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
        } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
        // Do work
        }
        }
        }];
        */


        let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: {
            result, error in
            if ((error) != nil){

            }
            else if (result.isCancelled){

            } else {
                if(result.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email")){  //<-- error here

                }
            }

        })



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Swift 1.2 automatically casts all `NSSet` objects (the ones that coming from external libs/sdks/frameworks etc...) to `Set` structure you need to call `contains` instead of `containsObject` for such things ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Set/s:FVSs3Set8containsuRq_Ss8Hashable_FGS_q__Fq_Sb)).

Comment: Thank you! Could you also tell me what might be the reason for autocomplete (intellisense) not working in handler (block?) ?

Comment: @user2441104 In your case it is probably because you didn't specify explicitly the types of the block's parameters. Try to write: `..., handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) -> Void in ...`.
Also it might be just lagging :)